# Doctrine - BaseClassName Not found

Tags: doctrine

I'm trying to setup doctrine in my project and whenever I call on a class, e.g.

```
$dealer = Doctrine_Core::getTable( 'Dealers' ).find(1);
```

Then I get Fatal Error: Class BaseSchools not found.

I know those files exist, since I did `Doctrine_Core::generateModelsFromDb` and I can see them

Somehow my paths to my models/generated folder aren't being told to my Dealers class.

In my bootstrap.php file I have:

```
Doctrine::loadModels( array( WWWROOT_PATH . 'models/generated', WWWROOT_PATH . 'models') );
```

I don't get any errors, if I change the path to the wrong path, it throws an error so I'm assuming that i'm doing it correctly.

Anyway any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Ended up being that I didn't have this autoloader:

spl_autoload_register( array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload' ) );

Comment: You should create an answer below with the solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that I didn't include this line in my boostrap file:

```
spl_autoload_register( array('Doctrine', 'autoload' ) );
```